# How to construct a new Matrix() in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

I'm getting an error with

```
use LinearAlgebra;
var M = Matrix((3,4, 5.1), (5,6,1.3));
```

How do I correctly construct M?  I feel like I knew the answer once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I correctly construct M?

What you meant to do is:

```
use LinearAlgebra;
var M = Matrix([3.0,4.0, 5.1], [5.0,6.0,1.3]);
```

The [`Matrix()` overload](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.html#LinearAlgebra.Matrix) you were trying to call expects 1D arrays, denoted by the bracket syntax, e.g. `[1,2,3]`. Instead, your example was passing tuples, denoted by the parentheses syntax, e.g. `(1,2,3)`.